# Flask/Jinja - Rerender UITab on Click Or Timer without page refresh

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, jquery-ui-tabs

I Have a Flask server with a Jinja Template which is tracking current status of network PC's. Below is a screenshot of the setup.

[image]

Each Gauge at the top represents the count of active clients, on that workgroup, but is also a filter to see only that workgroup.

Each Gauge represents a `UITab`. When I click on the Gauge, it takes me to the tab, and uses `Jinja` comparison to check if it belongs in the table of the tab.

The Issue - I would like to dynamically update the page, without refresh. Currently, the gauges will throttle up and down, no problem dynamically, but the data table's do not properly re render.

If I move a workstation from workgroup01 to workgroup02, the gauge will throttle, but the line item will not move to the correct table. I am using AJAX on a timer for the gauges, but I need to somehow retrigger the `computer.current_workgroup == workgroup` check in order to get dynamic updates on the table

Is this possible to do with Jinja, or do I have to write a long custom function to do this? I am trying to avoid the custom work for logistical reasons.

Here is some relevant code as it relates to document flow, I've tried to strip out non essential code please let me know if more is needed.

### index.html

```
<div id="tabs" >
    <ul id="gaugeList">
        {% for workgroup in context['workgroup_list'] %}
            <li><h3>
                <a class="gaugeCell" id="{{ workgroup }}"
                   href="#tabs-{{ workgroup.name }}">

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //  The  gauges
                </script>
                </a></h3></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% for workgroup in context['workgroup_list'] %}

    <div id="tabs-{{ workgroup.name }}" class="scrollable">

        <table class="tablesorter">

            <thead>
            <!-- Header stuff -->
            </thead>

            <tbody id="{{workgroup.name}}_table" class="table_body">
                {% for computer in context['computer_list'] %}


                {% if (computer.current_workgroup == workgroup.shorthand) or (workgroup.name == 'All') %}

                <tr id="{{computer.name}}" class="parent">
                <td>
                <-- TD's for table --> 
                </td>




            {% endif %}
            {% endfor%}
            </tbody>

        </table>
        </div>


    {% endfor %}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for reading

Comment: I think you are looking for ajax.

Comment: I am trying to avoid a custom ajax solution if there is an out of box Jinja solution

Comment: I don't think that there is jinja solution. If you don't want to use ajax use web sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it can be achieved directly using jinja2, I would make an additional controller that returns the HTML for the table only (without html, header, body-tags and so on), for this you can use a jinja2 template.

If you have this, using jquery's .load(), you can get data from this controller every n seconds and updates the appropriate div from the main page. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: so as I look into this solution, would I want a new html file for each table, or 1 html file that has all tables. I don't really seem to understand lol... I am also seeing something in Jinja `macros` I wonder if I can leverage tghat

Comment: macros in jinja will not work, jinja won't allow you to do anything dynamic. With the information provided it is difficult to say what will work best, though if you have multiple tabs with tables I would make separate controllers for each and only update the visible one.